# URL is not loading properly in YII

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I am trying to setup a site in local machine. I found the project files from live site. I changed database settings and base url. My home page is loading properly. But all other url's redirects to apache dashboard.[image]

This is my home page.
Then I am trying to load http://localhost:8080/process.bridge-global.com/Home

It redirects to following page
[image]

**here is my routing in config/main.php**

```
    'urlManager' => array(

        'urlFormat' => 'path',

    'showScriptName' => false,

        'caseSensitive' => false,

        'rules' => array(

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',

             array('class' => 'application.components.TeamListRule'),

            'Home' => array('site/Home', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
             '<view:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>/'=>'landingPreview/landingPage',
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the problem is due to the fact you are not using the proper way for accessing to your website so for that you need to write your URL on this
form .

localhost/yourfolder/web/index.php/yourController/method

if you still have issue tell me

Comment: this is actually basic url writing method. i am using routing to rewrite this url

Answer (score 0):

From this information that you have provided, it looks like you didn't set up correctly your virtual host root. Your application is configuring to live inside of the root of the virtual host and your application is placed in some directory inside of the root. I will try to explain with your data:

- your virtual host root: http://localhost:8080/
- your application root (where is entry index.php): http://localhost:8080/process.bridge-global.com/

The solution is to make virtual host so that your application entry point is in the root of it:

- your virtual host root: http://localhost:8080/
- your application root (where is entry index.php): http://localhost:8080/

There are a lot of ways to do this.

One of them is to create a virtual host. From what I see you use XAMPP, so that is doable. You should consult documentation on how to do it.